# Is it possible to make Iframe alternate?

Tags: php

My problem:
I can display content of a php file including(image background) using iframe. When I go to include my php file using

```
    include("modules/form.php");
    or
    file_get_contents("modules/form.php");
```

it displays content, but background image becomes invisible. It is a big site. So, is there any alternate of iframe for this purpose? I do not want to use iframe because my ranking in google is becoming down.

Comment: Didn't realise anybody still used iframes nowadays, how very retro

Comment: It is a very old site. I want to change iframe.

Comment: Microsoft is using them all over their websites. I mean, okay, they invented it, but as you say: **very retro!** (E.g. https://login.live.com/)

Comment: @MarkBaker disqus is completely build on iframes ..

Comment: isn't iframe very harmful for seo?

Comment: It's bad read http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/do-we-still-need-to-avoid-using-frame-iframe-for-good-seo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't archive this using php , till far i know. PHP is a server side script it does not know anything from the client side. You can use jquery , first you will have to create a div and in it set the content of the page.Use the code below

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#divId').load(full url to modules/form.php);     // Paste the full url here
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Frame page : make sure you use complete path while linking images (http://yoursite.com/path/to/images/file.extension) and then i think it will fix the issue